# preg_match_all results in "Unknown Modifier '*' "

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping

I'm trying to write a Regular Expression to extract names from an HTML table, where the names are written in the following format: "Smith, Bob"

The regular Expression I'm using is: `[a-zA-Z]*,\s[a-zA-Z]*`

I keep getting the following error message when executing the code (in the second preg_match_all line): Unknown modifier '*'

I have changed the * to a +, only for the same error prompt. My code is the following:

```
$start = strpos($content,'<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" rules="all" border="1"             id="gvChart"'); 
$end = strpos($content,'</table>',$start) + 8;
$table = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

/* Regex */
preg_match_all("|<tr(.*)</tr>|U",$table,$player);
foreach ($player as $val) {
preg_match_all("[a-zA-Z]*,\s[a-zA-Z]*", $table, $name);
echo $name[0];
}
```

All Help would be much appreciated here, Thanks :)

Comment: I don't like to say it, but what about "O'Brian, Miles", or "Kennedy, John F."...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use a delimiter in your function... Try:

```
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]*,\s[a-zA-Z]*/", $table, $name);
```

or even:

```
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]*,\s[A-Z]*/i", $table, $name);
```